# sharepoint 2007 installation an installation package for the product microsoft office document lifecycle components cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2

When I try to install MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2, the installation stops and I receive the following error:
sharepoint 2007 installation an installation package for the product microsoft office document lifecycle components cannot be found. try installation again using a valid copy of installation package 'dlc.msi'.

What can be the reason for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.

I just searched the installation directory for 'dlc.msi' and installed it manually and it worked fine.

I belive that any error like this can be solved the same way